# get the remaining length and quantity using java and sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

I have few lengths and quantities. Eg., `1000 mm, 5 quantity; 500 mm, 5 quantity;` etc. Now, suppose, the end user asks for `300 mm, 6 quantity`, I pick it up from the first available option, i.e., `1000 mm, 5 quantity`.

Now, the remaining length is `100 mm, 2 quantity & 1000 mm, 3 quantity` (take out 300 mm 3 times from one 1000 mm (remaining 100 mm, 1 qauantity), another 3 times of 300 mm from another 1000 mm (remaining 100 mm, 1 qauantity), the others 3 quantities of 1000 mm are intact). I tried the following piece of code :

```
double x = Required_Length, y = Available_Length;

int n = Available_Quantity;

ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();

if(x < (y / 2))
{
       listA.add("" + (y - x));
}

else if((n * x) >= y)
{
       for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
       {
              while((y - (n * x)) > x)
              {
                     listA.add("" + (y - (n * x)));
              }
       }
}
```

> Explanation : If, half of available length is greater than or equal to
>   the required length, then, the returned length would be
>   `Available_Length - Required_Length. Else if Quantity * Required_Length`
>   is more than or equal to the `Available_Length`, then I tried using
>   loops, but, could not get the desired result.

Please guide me.

Comment: What on earth does this question have to do with SQL Server, or even Java for that matter?

Comment: hi, I need to do it in java and sql server

Comment: You still need this? Could you please provide Sqlfiddle for your data?